# RequireJS is not loading Vue.js properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, requirejs

I need to load `Vue.js` through `RequireJS`. I simply did

```
<script>
    require([
        'vue'
    ], function (Vue) {
        console.log('Vue loaded!');
    });
</script>
```

in console I can see `Vue loaded!` message, Vue-devtools detected Vue, but when I type

`let a = new Vue();`

I get

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`

What is more important, my Vue.js app can't not load because it also doesn't see `Vue.js`.

Comment: What happens when you log the Vue variable? ` console.log(Vue, 'Vue loaded!');`

Comment: @Ferrybig ```ƒ Vue (options) {
  if ("development" !== 'production' &&
    !(this instanceof Vue)
  ) {
    warn('Vue is a constructor and should be called with the `new` keyword');
  }
  this._init(options);
} "Vue loaded"```